# creating a method to return a range of random values

Tags: c#, random, range

Consider the following code. The basic idea is to return a comma separated list of 20 numbers any of which can be a value between 0 and the max allowed value. On each pass through the loop the potential max value allowed for the next value in the list reduces by whatever last random value picked was.

So it works... but it sucks. The problem being it's always going to produce output like this:

"22,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"

"17,3,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"

"23,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"

How could it be modified to allow for a more even distribution of values across the range?

```
    public static string RandomRangeOfValuesMaker(int total)
    {
        var remainingTotal = total + 1;

        const int numberOfValues = 20;

        var rand = new Random();

        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = 1; i < numberOfValues + 1; i++)
        {
            var currentRandomNumber = rand.Next(remainingTotal);

            remainingTotal = remainingTotal - currentRandomNumber;

            builder.Append(currentRandomNumber + ",");
        }

        var rangeOfValues = builder.ToString().Remove(builder.ToString().Length - 1);

        return rangeOfValues;
    }
```

Comment: You decrement the max random number each loop, eventually that reaches 0 then you only get 0s hence all the ranges sum to 24.

Comment: Also `Random` uses the time to create a random number. When you are calling `Next` to near each other its likly to return the same number. You could use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.

Comment: @NtFreX No, as long as he keeps reusing the same instance, `.Next()` isn't broken like that. It might be a smell though that he construct the `Random` instance inside this method, if he keeps calling this method in a loop. `Random` seeds the internal data from time, when constructed, but doesn't use time after that so calling `.Next()` in a loop is fine, as long as it is on the same instance.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Can you give us an indication of what kind of sequence of number would be acceptable to you? I mean, since you're asking for 20 numbers which should sum up to 25, you don't have much leeway in terms of variation. You could use a weighted table of numbers perhaps, one that favors smaller numbers more. This wouldn't rule out higher numbers but would make them less likely to appear consistently.

Comment: If the results are evenly distributed across the range, is it right to call them random (particularly if you know what the range is)?

Comment: You said, *"On each pass through the loop the potential max value allowed for the next value in the list reduces by whatever last random value picked was."*. Why do you do that? Is it required? It is the reason that you are ending up with so many zeroes. Your first statement sounds like you just want a random list of 20 numbers between 0 and max.

Comment: so the general idea is, if you have a starting amount of say, 40... all the values across the range have to add up to 40... does that make sense?

Comment: To produce weighted numbers from 1 to 24, you can use this: `var temp1 = rand.NextDouble(); var currentQuestionMark = 1 + (int)(24 * temp1 * temp1);` This will reverse exponentially pick lower numbers. See if it makes a more acceptable sequence.

Comment: However, this will only allow you to get lower numbers while still having a chance of higher numbers. Most likely, unless you shuffle the list, you will always have this kind of behavior where the end of the list is full (to one extent or another) of 0's.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen problem is you then get a sequence like so:

"3,13,18,18,8,5,1,13,1,21,1,6,18,21,13,1,1,1,22,10"

That doesn't add up to what maxNumber argument was (24 in the example above).

Comment: @ar.dll: Wait, are you saying that you *require* that the numbers sum to a certain value? That is a very different problem than the one you stated. This is a *partitioning problem*.

Comment: Well, not really, he stated that the max number for the random number calculation was reduced by the produced number each iteration, this is a sort of roundabout way to say that the sum will be that number.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I've renamed the argument.. hopefully this will reduce some confusion.

Comment: Stating the requirements explicitly will reduce confusion to 0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UPDATE: I misunderstood the poorly stated constraints on the problem; my original answer addresses the problem "Generate n random numbers less than m, in descending order".  Original answer is appended below.

The actual problem is "generate a random partition of the number m into n parts".

There are many ways to do that. Here's one; it is O(m) in time and O(n) in space. Can you improve that?

```
static Random random = new Random();
static IEnumerable<int> Partition(int number, int parts) {
  int[] partition = new int[parts];
  for(int i = 0; i < number; ++i)
    partition[random.Next(parts)] += 1;
  return partition;
}
```

The algorithm is: we have `parts` crates and `number` apples; we randomly throw each apple into a crate until we're out of apples, and we have partitioned all the apples.

Now your program is the one-liner

```
Partition(maxNumber, 20).OrderByDescending(x=>x).CommaSeparated();
```

using the helper functions below.

The key thing to note in both this solution and Kyle's solution is not the algorithm that generates the partition -- like I said, there are lots of ways to do that. Rather, the key thing is *don't try to do too much in one function*.  You went wrong when you tried to ensure the sum property and the monotonicity and the comma separation all in the same place.  Sorting 20 numbers is cheap; outsource the problem. Comma-separating a bunch of stuff is cheap; outsource that problem too. Write small functions that each do one thing well, and *then* compose them into larger functions.

---

> How could it be modified to allow for a more even distribution of values across the range?

Choose the numbers *first* and *then* sort them.

Let's break it down. First: an infinite sequence of random numbers:

```
private static Random random = new Random();    
public static IEnumerable<int> RandomNumbers(int max)
{
  while(true) yield return random.Next(max);
}
```

Now that you have that your program becomes a one-liner.

```
public static string RandomRangeOfValuesMaker(int maxNumber)
{
  return string.Join(",", RandomNumbers(maxNumber).Take(20).OrderByDescending(x=>x));
}
```

Any time you are doing something involving a sequence, as yourself **can I use built-in sequence operators to express my desired workflow? Can I build my own sequence operators?**

For example, we could make another sequence operator one-liner:

```
public static string CommaSeparated<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) 
{
  return string.Join(",", items);
}
```

And now your program becomes even more elegant:

```
public static string RandomRangeOfValuesMaker(int maxNumber)
{
  return RandomNumbers(maxNumber)
    .Take(20)
    .OrderByDescending(x=>x)
    .CommaSeparated();
}
```

What do you want? 20 random numbers, ordered in descending order, separated by commas. So how should your program read? **It should say I want 20 random numbers ordered descending, separated by commas**.  Write your program so that it looks like a description of the problem it is trying to solve. It will be easier to understand, easier to maintain, and easier to see that it is correct.

Comment: From @ar.dll specification I see that `sequence[i] <= maxNumber - Sum(sequence[0]..sequence[i-1])`

Comment: Well, your (revised) answer makes mine look painfully verbose! Now all I've got to do is scrabble around in what *I* remember from University and try and work out how exactly the code you've given does what it does! =)

Comment: @Rob: We have `parts` empty crates and `number` apples. We throw each apple into a randomly chosen crate until we are out of apples, and hey, we have randomly partitioned the apples.

Comment: @EricLippert, when you put it like that,.... Thank you! =) It's Friday afternoon/early evening here and my brain completely skipped over the `+= 1`. That's my excuse, and I'm sticking to it! =)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a sequence of random integers that add up to a particular sum, the easiest thing is to first pick a sequence of random integers in the range [0, sum], sort them, then return the differences:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetSequenceWithSum( Random rand, int count, int sum )
{
    // Get a list of count-1 random numbers in the range [0, sum] in ascending order.
    // This partitions the range [0, sum] into count different bins of random size.
    var partition = Enumerable.Range( 0, count - 1 )
                              .Select( _ => rand.Next( 0, sum + 1 ) )
                              .OrderBy( x => x );

    // Yield the size of each partition in the range.
    int previous = 0;
    foreach( int value in partition )
    {
        yield return value - previous;
        previous = value;
    }

    yield return sum - previous;
}
```

I can't say precisely what distribution this gives you, but it will give you one that *looks* "even".

The simplest way to understand why this works is to think of it this way:

Say you want a bunch of sticks of random length, but when you glue the sticks together you want their lengths to add up to some specific length.

One way to accomplish this is to start with a stick of the length you want and to cut it randomly into the number of pieces you want.  That way the sum of the lengths of each of the pieces is the length of the piece you started with.

This code "cuts" the stick by first picking random numbers which represent the locations at which we'll cut the big stick.  It then puts the cut positions in order so we know which cuts are next to each other.  Then all it has to do is subtract consecutive cuts to get the lengths of the stick pieces.

Comment: Usage: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", GetSequenceWithSum(new Random(), 20, total)));`

Comment: yes this seems to return the type of distribution I'm looking for... I haven't got a clue how that code works though! can you explain :)

Comment: @ar.dll: Suppose we generate four numbers: `a, b, c, d` such that all are between 0 and sum, and they are sorted descending. We produce the partition `a, b-a, c-b, d-c, sum-d`.  Plainly this adds up correctly: `a + b - a + c - b + d - c + sum - d` is equal to `sum`.  Plainly all are not negative. Plainly all are less than or equal to sum. So it satisfies your requirements; the only remaining question is how good the distribution is.

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface this with: Read the answer from Eric Lippert - what he says is almost certainly more correct than me (pssst.. he studied Mathematics at University AND worked on the C# compiler, amongst other things, at Microsoft!).

A rudimentary implementation of your requirement that the function return X values that sum to Y could be written as:

```
public static string StringyRandomNumbersThatAddUpToMaxNumber(int sumOfRandomNumbers, int numberOfValuesToReturn)
{
    var randomNumbers = RandomNumbersThatAddUpToMaxNumber(new List<int>(), sumOfRandomNumbers, numberOfValuesToReturn);
    return string.Join(",", randomNumbers);
}

public static IEnumerable<int> RandomNumbersThatAddUpToMaxNumber(List<int> randomNumbers, int sumOfRandomNumbers, int numberOfValuesToReturn)
{
    var randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

    while (randomNumbers.Sum() < sumOfRandomNumbers)
    {
        var ceiling = (randomNumbers.Any() ? randomNumbers.Sum() : sumOfRandomNumbers) / 2;
        var newNumber = randomNumberGenerator.Next(ceiling);

        if (randomNumbers.Sum() + newNumber <= sumOfRandomNumbers)
        {
            randomNumbers.Add(newNumber);
        }
    }

    if (numberOfValuesToReturn > randomNumbers.Count())
    {
        randomNumbers.Remove(randomNumbers.Max());

        return RandomNumbersThatAddUpToMaxNumber(randomNumbers, sumOfRandomNumbers, numberOfValuesToReturn);
    }

    return randomNumbers;
}
```

In theory, it may never return or throw a `StackOverflowException`, but in practice it's likely that it will.

I'm not in any way, shape, or form confident that the resultant numbers could be considered to be truly random (as it eliminates the highest value on each recursion to allow it more "working space" to find more values to satisfy the requirement that they all add up to Y), so please take this code with that note.

Comment: FYI your algorithm is a *partition refinement* algorithm. Consider the following sketch of an alternate version of your algorithm. Suppose we wish to partition 20 into 5 parts. We start with `{20}`. We don't yet have 5 parts, so we "randomly" choose a partition and randomly subdivide it. `{{{14}, {6}}}`.  We still don't have enough parts, so we randomly choose a partition, but we bias the choice: 14/20 chance of choosing 14, 6/20 chance of choosing 6.  We pick 14 and randomly subdivide it `{{{{1}, {13}}, {6}}}`.  And so on.

Comment: This ensures that the sum is never wrong, and that the recursion terminates. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_refinement for more thoughts on this class of algorithms.